# How to pass predicate to linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

Given a method signature like so...

```
IEnumerable<Student> get(Func<DataRow, bool> predicate);
```

How can I pass the predicate argument along to a linq expression?

```
public override IEnumerable<Student> get(Func<System.Data.DataRow, bool> predicate = null) {
    var students = from student in _dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
              join attendance in _dataSet.Tables[1].AsEnumerable() 
              on student.Field<int>("id") equals attendance.Field<int>("idStudent")
              join grade in _dataSet.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
              on student.Field<int>("id") equals grade.Field<int>("idStudent")
              join assignment in _dataSet.Tables[3].AsEnumerable()
              on student.Field<int>("id") equals assignment.Field<int>("idStudent")
              // where predicate??
              // select blahblahblah
    // return statement

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
where predicate == null || predicate(student)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `predicate` is a function that takes `DataRow` as an input -- use it like `where predicate(student)`.

```
var students = from student in _dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    ...
    where predicate == null || predicate(student)
    select student
```

Comment: Since it looks like predicate can be null, it will take a little more work to account for the possibility that it's not provided.